# What is the best way to achieve data persistence jquery/php?

Tags: php, jquery, session, persistence

I'm designing a simple board game in jquery/php. The state of the board is currently stored server-side in a php session variable as an array. Each turn is executed as an ajax call to php, which executes logic to update this array, and returns the array to jquery to render as html. I'm achieving persistence of board state with php session variables...but I don't think this is good practise. I can't even play it in multiple tabs, because the browser treats both tabs as part of the same session. I would like to find a solution other than store board state in a database...but if this is the only reasonable solution please let me know :). Thanks!

Comment: That's probably because you are using same variable names for both tabs; try using $_SESSION['game_tab1'] and $_SESSION['game_tab2'], .. basically append an id referencing the tab

Comment: If using sessions, I would like to have a separate session for each instance of the game, rather than storing all instances of a game in the same session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a javascript library like [Lawnchair](http://westcoastlogic.com/lawnchair/) to store the data on the client side?

> by default, lawnchair will persist using dom storage but if other adapters are available and dom 
>   storage isn't supported by the currently executing javascript runtime. lawnchair will attempt each 
>   successive adapter until it finds one that works. easy.

It Dom storage spans across tabs as well.

via [Dive.Into.Javascript](http://www.diveintojavascript.com/javascript-apis/web-storage-dom-storage)

> The data stored in the local storage area does not expire and spans accross different tabs and/or windows

Answer (score 0):

you can store the data in client side using javascript.  Either place in hidden fields or use mechanisms like [jquery data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) like this:

```
$('body').data('player1-pos-x', x);
$('body').data('player1-pos-y', y);
```

The issue with it is when you refresh the browser, everything is lost.

Another way is store data both in sever side and client side.  you can store a game-id, session-id pair to group games under the same session.  When browser refresh, you'll have all the game that session relates to and make a decision with the data.

Comment: What if the user opens a new tab...won't this be treated the same as on browser refresh? the client side fields will be empty (as if refreshed)..but session data will be populated? Opening many tabs will result in loading the same game in each tab wouldn't it?

Comment: You open a tab and set game-id to null, then make a decision to create a new game or load existing game associated with the same session id.  You need to use ajax to query the server side for a list of game id or create new game-id then load the related data as appropriate.  This way you can have multiple tab open different game. bear in mind this make the system relatively complicated as if loading the same game can result in conflict which you need to handle and each move player make need to be stored on both client side and server side